# ionic 2 application long loading time

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-directives, ionic-native

I have developed ionic 2 application but the main issue i am facing is the load time on start of application it takes minutes to load application. I am using limited plugins but still facing the issue also a white screen is shown after splash screen manually hides.

Comment: Josh Morony did some videos on remote debugging apps on Youtube. iirc he went thru the process of identifying long running processes via Chrome. Maybe from that you can evaluate what's causing the biggest delays.

Answer (score 1):

Add --prod when you build the app. It will minify css and js files.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the most recent version of Ionic Cloud and building with the production flag will reduce your cold start time dramatically.

```
npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save

ionic build --prod
```

It will take longer to build but you'll have a much faster cold start time.

Comment: i don't want to switch to ionic 3 can i still use this command to update cloud-angular?

Comment: That `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save` will only update cloud-angular. Updating the Ionic CLI and cordova are separate commands. However, you can also try just running `ionic build --prod` before updating and see if that works.

Comment: yes it is working so don't need to update cloud right?
and thanks for your quick response.

Comment: If you are getting no errors then you do not have to update. However, updating will always give you the best results as the Ionic team has been releasing updates rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mass importing in `app.component.ts`? Usually when you have a ton of imports, you slow down the entire application. I would check when you test in the browser, all of the unused imports. That would at least help speed up the initial load time.